# How to Json Parse string containing "@"?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a json object that looks like this:

```
{\"household\":{\"@id\":\"36963416\",\"@uri\":\"https://serviceapi.com/v1/Households/36963416\",\"@oldID\":\"\",\"@hCode\":\"8Z6iDWwZ7Rr3uY/atTYRMQ==\",\"householdName\":\"Test Test\",\"householdSortName\":\"Test\",\"householdFirstName\":\"Test\",\"lastSecurityAuthorization\":null,\"lastActivityDate\":null,\"createdDate\":\"2015-06-22T15:53:31\",\"lastUpdatedDate\":null}}
```

I am having difficulty using JSON.parse() because of the pesky "@" signs.  How should I parse this so that I can get the household @id value?

Comment: Do you know the person who is responsible for constructing the JSON response? Tell him to change it.

Comment: or .. replacing all @ upfront ?

Comment: Yes, javascript, sorry.  The service provider won't change the response.  Stripping out all the @ signs would probably work but not sure how.

Comment: `@` is not a special character in JSON. It shouldn't cause you any problems to parse it. The escaped `"` characters OTOH are an issue.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nocadipele/1/edit?html,output - This parses without a problem. The ``\`` characters have special meaning in a JavaScript string but if I had escaped them to represent them in the string as data, it would have made the JSON invalid.

Comment: @Tim Castelijns - The @ symbol typically represents a node attribute or namespace when translating XML to json, e.g., Json.NET, etc.  You can read more about it here: [Converting Between XML and JSON](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the household `id` is done with this JavaScript expression:

```
var object= JSON.parse(yourString);
object.household["@id"]
```

specifically:

```
var obj= JSON.parse("{\"household\":{\"@id\":\"36963416\",\"@uri\":\"https://serviceapi.com/v1/Households/36963416\",\"@oldID\":\"\",\"@hCode\":\"8Z6iDWwZ7Rr3uY/atTYRMQ==\",\"householdName\":\"Test Test\",\"householdSortName\":\"Test\",\"householdFirstName\":\"Test\",\"lastSecurityAuthorization\":null,\"lastActivityDate\":null,\"createdDate\":\"2015-06-22T15:53:31\",\"lastUpdatedDate\":null}}");
console.log('id:', obj.household['@id']);
```

Comment: The OP says the problem is with `JSON.parse`, not with accessing the property afterwards.

Comment: I enclosed his string above in quotes and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't reproduce the problem described in the question either.

Comment: I think the problem is using `object.@id` will not work, you need to revert to the `[]` notation for that. What kind of jerks put `@` in their keys anyways?

Comment: Some XML to JSON serializers will make XML attributes have a leading `@` as opposed to an XML element.  In JSON, there is no "attribute" concept, so it is the next best thing.  It does make it less convenient for programmers, though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the JSON normally:

```
var test = "{\"household\":{\"@id\":\"36963416\",\"@uri\":\"https://serviceapi.com/v1/Households/36963416\",\"@oldID\":\"\",\"@hCode\":\"8Z6iDWwZ7Rr3uY/atTYRMQ==\",\"householdName\":\"Test Test\",\"householdSortName\":\"Test\",\"householdFirstName\":\"Test\",\"lastSecurityAuthorization\":null,\"lastActivityDate\":null,\"createdDate\":\"2015-06-22T15:53:31\",\"lastUpdatedDate\":null}}";
var objTest = JSON.parse(test);
console.log(objTest);
console.log(objTest["@id"]);
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zmdua9x9/)

Comment: The question says they can't. This just means you can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: "I can't reproduce the problem" is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You said that there isn't a problem. That isn't an answer.

Comment: @Quentin There are plenty of questions on StackOverflow where the OP believes there is a problem with a certain approach when there isn't one. I've demonstrated how there isn't one with a full working example.